# Список и количество вложенных элементов

Tags: sql, mysql

Таблица вида id, ownderID, name

ownderID ссылается на id в той же таблице, иными словами, обычная структура, как в проводнике.
Если ownderID = 0, значит элемент лежит в корне.

Можно ли как-то одним запросом получить список элементов с отдельным полем с количеством вложенных элементов (на 1 ступень, не больше).

Если таблицы разные, left join у меня хорошо работает в подобных случаях. А с одной таблицей что-то забуксовал я. Выручайте!

Answer (score 1):

Если с двумя таблицами получается, то и с одной получится:

```
FROM T as a LEFT JOIN T as b
```